# Laying tile on a floor with foundation settlement

Tags: tile, foundation

I want to lay tile on the whole 1st floor(concrete).
Due to foundation settlement my floor has 1 inch elevation variance from one side to another(but no sharp dips or bumps).
Should I use the highest spot of the floor as a starting point and level everything with the tile glue to make the floor perfectly even(make the floor 0 variance) or should I just apply even layer of tile glue over the whole floor and let the tile have slope like foundation does?

Comment: Let it slope.   1” over a large space is not too bad. If you want to fix the slope do it before tiling with floor leveler.

Comment: tile glue?  are you talking thinset or are you thinking vinyl tiles and vinyl tile adhesive?  I can't imagine either would work well with a 1" thick layer.  Do you have a 2" square notch trowel for the area that is 1" lower?

Comment: I'm talking about tile mortar. And 1 inch layer of mortar works perfectly well, I've seen worse. Sometimes people do leveling with tile mortar and trowel is not necessary for that. I'm not saying it's best/optimal solution though.

Comment: Im doing everything alone and not sure if leveling 1200sq feet can be done by 1 person. The compound will dry out while I'm doing that.  So I'm thinking just to let the tile slope is a good option.

Comment: I already did leveling with mortar up to 1.5 inches and haven't had any problems at least for 3 years. The only issue is you need a lot of mortar.

Comment: The fact that you have a _smooth_ surface sounds much more important than a dead _level_ surface. So long as there are no bumps or dips to telegraph through the tiles to make trip hazards, I wouldn't worry too much about a slight slope. You indicate a 1" variation in height, but A) don't mention the run over which that 1" happens, or B) how you've determined that 1" variation. What are you measuring from to determine the slope?

Comment: I used ziplevel to measure foundation slope.